# IKE VPN connection kills Ethernet connection

Tags: windows-10, vpn, routing, ethernet, network-adapter

On a laptop with Windows 10, I have set up an IKE VPN connection using the native Windows VPN client. It connects to the VPN fine: the corresponding adapter shows that it's connected and `RasMan` puts an event in the Event log saying that the connection is successfully established. But at the moment it connects, the Ethernet connection via which I'm connected to the router gets disconnected (Widows marks it as "no internet connection"). The computers in the LAN stay accessible, but everything behind the router can't be accessed, all pings to anything outside the LAN fail.

The route table looks as follows:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
19...00 ff d9 8d 18 e3 ......TAP-ProtonVPN Windows Adapter V9
27...........................My VPN
 1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 8...48 5a b6 c9 ae 3b ......Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
 4...4a 5a b6 c9 ae 3b ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
22...4a 5a b6 c9 a6 3b ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
15...28 d2 44 b9 58 46 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
10...48 5a b6 c9 ae 3c ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.106   4260
        0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link        10.10.10.1     36
## My VPN IP ##  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.106   4261
     10.10.10.1  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.1    291
      127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
      127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
    192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.106   4516
  192.168.1.106  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.106   4516
  192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.106   4516
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.106   4516
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.10.10.1     36
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.106   4516
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.1    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

`10.10.10.1` is the IP that VPN server assigns to my computer.
The adapters' properties are OK, as far as I can understand.

What can be the reason of such behavior? What should I additionally check?

UPD: An additional information that may be relevant: the server logs indicate that the connection from my laptop gets successfully established, as far I can tell:

```
....
Sep  2 12:34:41 ip-172-26-9-177 charon: 08[MGR] IKE_SA ikev2-pubkey[47] successfully checked out
Sep  2 12:34:41 ip-172-26-9-177 charon: 08[KNL] querying policy 10.10.10.1/32 === 0.0.0.0/0 in
Sep  2 12:34:41 ip-172-26-9-177 charon: 08[KNL] querying policy 10.10.10.1/32 === 0.0.0.0/0 fwd
Sep  2 12:34:41 ip-172-26-9-177 charon: 08[MGR] checkin IKE_SA ikev2-pubkey[47]
Sep  2 12:34:41 ip-172-26-9-177 charon: 08[MGR] checkin of IKE_SA successful
.....
```

I have another VPN server in the same subnet with the first server I mention above, their configurations are identical (except particular IPs, certificate SANs etc). They both run Debian with Strongswan, configured by myself. And I have another computer within the same my LAN, with Windows 2008, that works fine via the latter VPN server. I did not have much troubles setting them up. But I have very few experience with networking with Windows 10. I suppose there is some subtle nuance in networking settings I missed.

what additional information can shed light on the situation?

Answer (score 0):

> I have set up an IKE VPN connection using the native Windows VPN
> client.

Microsoft VPN does not enable Split Tunnel by default and so you cannot use Internet outside the LAN.

You need to see if you can enable Split Tunnel.

[Microsoft VPN Split Tunnel](https://www.perimeter81.com/glossary/vpn-split-tunneling)

> Click on the settings options in your VPN
>
> Select Split tunneling to get options to manage your VPN connection
> based on the URL or application
>
> Select the applications or sites you want with VPN and the one you
> want to access directly with the open network
>
> Complete the settings
>
> Test the VPN split tunnel connection by clicking on a selected URL to
> see if they pass through the VPN or not

Comment: By the LAN, I mean the computers in my apartment, physically wired (or WiFied) to the router. I can't access anything at all except them. Without split tunneling, i still can have access to the Internet, but all my traffic should pass through the VPN. In my case, I have not access to anything at all, neither via VPN, nor directly,

Comment: If you wish all traffic through your VPN, that can restrict traffic. Disconnect VPN, restart and see if everything is connecting on your LAN the way you wish.

Comment: I did it several times... Nothing changes...

Comment: Try removing your VPN profile. There seems to be something else wrong.

Comment: Removed and recreated, rebooted both the server and the laptop several times. Did not help. When the VPN is disconnected, everything's fine, as well as without VPN profile at all, but when I connect to it, the ethernet connection gets marked "without access to the Internet" and I lose access to everything outside my LAN

Comment: Try enabling Split Tunnel as suggested because you say all is fine with VPN disconnected.

Comment: I've done it, the connection doesn't drop anymore, but now all my traffic goes over ISP untunnelled. That's not what I want, I'd prefer all my traffic to go via VPN. Perhaps I should learn more how to set up split tunneling with Strongswan. Anyway, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: So I have answered your question.  You can’t have it both ways.  I use split tunnel and organize my traffic accordingly

Comment: I don't think so. It's rather a workaround than a solution and it requires additional efforts. As I said in the update to my question, there's another machine by my side that works fine via very similar VPN server without any split tunneling.

Comment: My solution is not a workaround. What I posted is how tunneling works (split or not split). You cannot have traffic limited to your tunnel and have it outside as well. What I posted is how (almost) all VPN solutions work. Been there, done that.